# Android ViewModel transform data from Sharedpreferences using Transformation.map

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, viewmodel, transformation, flatbuffers

I am trying to learn modern Android developing. I have application which is getting data from network in separate Thread and store it as String into SharedPreferences. This data are flatbuffers bytes. Now im trying develop ViewModel using this data for my Fragment.

Android Architecture Components is new for me and not everything is understanded by me. 
Can You ensure me that this piece of code is correct and if yes what i can do better. If not scold me and show me right path please.

```java
package com.lorkan.NetworkBypass.UI.technology;

import android.app.Application;
import android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import com.lorkan.NetworkBypass.LiveData.SharedPreferenceStringLiveData;

public class TechnologyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private LiveData<TechnologyManagerFlatBuffer> techManagerFlatBuffer;
    private LiveData<String> techManagerString;

    public TechnologyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application.getApplicationContext());
        techManagerString = new SharedPreferenceStringLiveData(prefs,"TechnologyManagerFlatBuffer","");
        techManagerFlatBuffer = Transformations.map(techManagerString, s ->{
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(s.getBytes());
            return TechnologyManagerFlatBuffer.getRootTechnologyManagerFlatBuffer(bb);
        });
    }

    public LiveData<TechnologyManagerFlatBuffer> getTechManagerFlatBuffer() {
        return techManagerFlatBuffer;
    }
}
```

TechnologyManagerFlatBuffer is ofcourse flatbuffer class generated via flatbuffer compiler and SharedPreferenceStringLiveData class is getted from this thread 
https://gist.github.com/idish/f46a8327da7f293f943a5bda31078c95#file-booleansharedpreferencelivedata-java-L10

Comment: I'm not familiar with these Android APIs so I am not sure, but one thing that is a bad idea is to store a FlatBuffer in `String`, since a `String` is made out of `char` which are not byte sized. It may even decode them from/to UTF-8 if you're unlucky, which would corrupt the FlatBuffer. I suggest storing them directly as a `byte[]` or `ByteBuffer` when you receive them from the network, and keeping them that way.

Comment: i understand your point but Sharedpreferences can store only Int,bool,floats and string i think so the choise is easy. Transform byte array into String put into my prefs and restore bytes from String with getBytes(). Value is value i an only wondering about Transformation.map to be more specific, will it be executed in Fragment UI thread or in thread which perform storing flatbuffer to Sharedpreferences? Perhaps i should change "map" to "switchMap" still digging to understand everything properly.

Comment: Then don't use `SharedPreferences`. You are likely corrupting the FlatBuffer data.